# Mobile menu width is bigger than screen on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to customize the header menu on mobile for a website. I use wordpress, elementor free and a paid theme from WP. The issue is that on mobile, the dark blue burger menu has a width larger than the screen size. I am trying to add a max width of 100% but it doesnt work. Any ideas?
https://red-beetle-roti.instawp.xyz/products/status-boards/

i tried setting a width and max width of 100% to .navbar.menu-style-flyout .navbar-inner but it doesnt do anything.
The issue might not appear on a desktop when you use inspect element , but it does on a real phone
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr2uZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

On the mobile screen, I can see that the footer elements are not optimized, decreasing the font size of the links down on the web page in the footer section will do.
As I don't have the access to complete code I just changes the Download Now text font to 5px to test and it worked.
You can see it here.

[image: Mobile Screen]

For any queries do let me know.

Comment: Also you need to work on the CSS for this website, I see many things not optimized for the mobile web view.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Elementor > Tools and clicked on Regenerate CSS & Data. This seems to have fixed the issue